# Jmeter File Upload. Faster in Chrome - Slower in Jmeter

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing

Im testing a File upload scenario in a Web application. The response times for uploading a 500MB file in Chrome is 21secs and in Jmeter it is 30secs. For a 5GB file the difference is more than a minute. Chrome is able to achieve higher upload/transfer speeds compared to Jmeter.
I have also tried with concurrent pool size as 6. But the behaviour is same.
Screenshot of the HTTP request is attached.The Jmeter version is 2.13. Can anyone please suggest as when load testing the difference can become much bigger.

[image: Request Screenshot]

Comment: Seems like the request to upload file via HTTPS protocol is making difference here.